# Export TFS 2008 (Team Foundation Server) Groups and Permissions

Tags: security, tfs, audit

Is there a way to export all of TFS 2008 Groups and Permissions for an Audit?

Comment: +1 This is a fantastic question... just what I'm looking for today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at this?

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/srlteam/archive/2006/11/27/TFS-Permission-Manager-1.0-is-Finally-out.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I'm the guy who wrote TFS Project Audit and I'd like to clarify a few things about my tool.  First, it works on a project basis for TFS 2008 or a collection basis for 2010.  It can report on a specific collection or all collections on a TFS server.  These are enhancements I made in the newest version, released only a few days ago.  Also, the output can be restricted to a specific group, Project Administrators, for example, across a project, collection, or the entire server.

I am always soliciting but rarely receiving feedback on this pet project of mine, so please feel free to leave suggestions for future releases!  I have plenty of ideas in mind but it would help to know where my time is best spent, because this projectis hardly all I do with my days.

To prove it is really me, I'll give Saul a shout at tfsprojects.codeplex.com.  Thanks a lot Saul!

Answer (score 3):

I looked at the TFS Permissions Manager mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561184/export-tfs-2008-team-foundation-server-groups-and-permissions/2568069#2568069) and couldn't easily figure out how to use this for an audit of user permissions.  That said I looked around and found a few other possible tools to help in this process:

1. [Team Foundation Server Administration Tool](http://tfsadmin.codeplex.com/) - This can be used to produce a list of TFS groups, users & permissions on a per project basis.  The utility uses a grid control to display the results and this can easily be copied and pasted into Excel, etc.
2. [TFS Project Audit](http://tfsprojects.codeplex.com/) - This tool generates output in an indented text format.  It too works on a per project basis however it lists the output grouped by TFS role.

I think both of the options I mention are more recently maintained than the TFS Permission Manager at the time of this writing.  Also, keep in mind that for purposes of a security audit I believe that the local & domain administrators groups in Windows Server have the ability to override any of the TFS permissions (at least with TFS 2008).